# rtsp method SETUP failed: 453 Not Enough Bandwith

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

On my raspberry pi 3+B, I'm using `ffmpeg+ffserver` to streaming two cams.

I run both commands at the background:

```
raspivid -o - t 0 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -n | ffmpeg -i - -crf 26 -preset ultrafast http://localhost:1234/feed1.ffm
python cam.py | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 80x60 -pix_fmt bgr24 -r 26 -i - -an -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast http://localhost:123/feed2.ffm
```

I have a laptop running a python script to read cam from raspberry pi via wireless.

When I read them individually, Each of them works fine. However, I get `rtsp method SETUP failed: 453 Not Enough Bandwith` when I try to read them at the same time.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error I faced:

```
method SETUP failed: 453 Not Enough Bandwidth
rtsp://192.168.101.155:1235/test1.sdp: Server returned 4XX Client Error,
but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}
```

How I Resolved:

I checked for **MaxClients** and **MaxBandwidth** parameters of the "[ffserver configuration file](http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html)". Finally I increased the number of **MaxClients** and **MaxBandwidth** to fix it.

For Example:

MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 100000